# LC-3 Motor Program (Strange Outputs)

Tags: assembly, lc3

So the output to my LC-3 program is giving me very strange characters/symbols. The objective of this program is to ask a user to input a 0 or a 1. If the user inputs a 1, the motor moves 120 degrees clockwise and then 90 degrees counter clockwise. If the user inputs a 0, the motor moves 50 degrees counter clockwise. 360 degrees = 36 steps. What is a step? A step is 10 degrees. The output prints out each step. For example, the user inputs a 0 then the output should say:

```
The motor moved 10 degrees CCW
The motor moved 10 degrees CCW
The motor moved 10 degrees CCW
The motor moved 10 degrees CCW
The motor moved 10 degrees CCW
```

It's a pretty interesting task imo but I'm having trouble actually making it work. Attached is my code and a screenshot of my output. Thanks for your time!

Can't embed picture since this account is new but the link of the screenshot of my output is below:
[http://tinypic.com/r/9roghf/9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZi29.png)

It also seems like the code didnt embedded correctly but please consider everything below as part of the code (Because it is!):

```
.ORIG x4000

    ;Constants
Prompt  .STRINGZ "Enter '1' to move moter 120 degrees clockwise then 90 degrees counter clockwise or Enter '0' to move motor 50 degree counter clockwise"

CW  .STRINGZ "The motor rotated 10 degrees clockwise"
CCW .STRINGZ "The motor rotated 10 degrees counterclockwise"

RL  ;Clear and Load Register 2
    AND R2, R2, #0
    ADD R2, R2, #12

    ;Clear and Load Register 3
    AND R3, R3, #0
    ADD R3, R3, #3

    ;Clear and Load Register 4
    AND R4, R4, #0
    ADD R4, R4, #2

    ;Clear And Load Register 5
    AND R5, R5, #0
    ADD R5, R5, #1

LL0 ;user input
    LEA R0, Prompt
    PUTS    ;Print String

    GETC    ;Receive user input
    OUT ;Prints out user input
    BRz LL3 ;If user input 0
    BRp LL1 ;If user input 1

    ;beginning of '1' loop
     ;120 degree clockwise rotation
LL1 LEA R0, CW

    ADD R2, R2, #-6 ;1 Bit Shift (Right) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #-3 ;1 Bit Shift (Right) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #6 ;1 Bit Shift (Right) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #3 ;1 Bit Shift (Right) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R3, R3, #-1 ;Decrement Loop (3x)
    BRp LL1

     ;90 degree counter clockwise rotation
LL2 LEA R0, CCW

    ADD R2, R2, #-3 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    BRz Stop ;After 90 degree turn

    ADD R2, R2, #-6 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #3 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #6 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R4, R4, #-1 ;Decrement Loop (2x)
    BRzp LL2

    ;beginning of '0' loop
     ;50 degree counter clockwise
LL3 LEA R0, CCW

    ADD R2, R2, #-3 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    BRz Stop ;After 50 degree turn

    ADD R2, R2, #-6 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #3 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #6 ;1 Bit Shift (Left) - 10 degree turn
    PUTS
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R0, #10
    OUT

    ADD R5, R5, #-1 ;Decrement Loop (1x)
    BRz LL3

Stop    HALT

    .END
```